# Gunicorn worker periodically crashes: 'socket is not registered'

Tags: python, gunicorn

Time to time (once a several hours) gunicorn worker fails with the following error:

```
[2014-10-29 10:21:54 +0000] [4902] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 4902
[2014-10-29 13:15:24 +0000] [4902] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 507, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/opt/test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 109, in init_process
    super(ThreadWorker, self).init_process()
  File "/opt/test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 120, in init_process
    self.run()
  File "/opt/test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 177, in run
    self.murder_keepalived()
  File "/opt/test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 149, in murder_keepalived
    self.poller.unregister(conn.sock)
  File "/opt/test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trollius/selectors.py", line 408, in unregister
    key = super(EpollSelector, self).unregister(fileobj)
  File "/opt/test/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trollius/selectors.py", line 243, in unregister
    raise KeyError("{0!r} is not registered".format(fileobj))
KeyError: '<socket._socketobject object at 0x7f823f454d70> is not registered'
...
...
[2014-10-29 13:15:24 +0000] [4902] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 4902)
[2014-10-29 13:15:24 +0000] [5809] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 5809
 ...
```

Configuration:

```
bind = '0.0.0.0:80'
workers = 1
threads = 4
debug = True
reload = True
daemon = True
```

I'm using:

```
Python 2.7.6
gunicorn==19.1.1
trollius==1.0.2
futures==2.2.0
```

Any ideas what may be the cause and how to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: any luck with this? I am facing exactly similar situation!

Comment: nope, still waiting for a help from community..

Comment: I am not sure, as I have to investigate more, but I think it may have to do with socket getting closed before it can be unregistered. I was planning to increase graceful timeout and see what happens. Will update here :)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue where I was getting time out errors from gunicorn worker. I am using sync worker and had `timeout` and `keepalive` default settings.
In my use-case my http request takes a long time to complete hence sync worker was timing out. I use `curl` as a http client which sends HTTP-1.1 requests. I increased the timeout to a crazy high values `3600` that is 1 hours and that works. However in server error logs I saw the same errors as yours. And here is my hypothesis regarding this error.
Since by default all http 1.1 requests are persistent server tries to reuse the connection by putting it back in the queue but no more than `keepalive` timeout. So when `keepalive` timeout occurs it unregister the socket so that it can not be reused and closes it down. Now since my timeout value is very high server tries to unregister an already unregistered socket multiple times however keepalive is still defaulting to 5 seconds so errors out. Therefore, I increased the ``keepalive`value as well to`3600```. So far it worked.

```
# http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html
timeout = 3600 # one hour timeout for long running jobs
keepalive = 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

I reported a gunicorn bug for this about a year ago, and the fix should be in gunicorn 19.6.0 and later: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/1258